# Need an Unanswered button above the Questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

We have recent, views, newest and votes buttons above the questions of users.
I think we also need an unanswered button there. It should be very much helpful for the users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always search for these questions using

```
user:me answers:0
```

Using answers:0 really only finds questions with no answers. You can instead search for your questions with no accepted answers using

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

If you use answers with a number other then 0, the number represents a lower limit (answers:1 returns all questions with at least 1 answer).

A button would make things easier, but most assuredly revive the discussion about the definition of "unanswered".

You can always make a bookmark in your browser using https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+answers:0 and get close to what you want.